# Sonata User - Injecting securityContext into Admin class

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Maybe dumb question but I used [easyExtends](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends/master/doc/index.html) to customize SonataUser and I'm trying to inject the security context into the Admin class.

But in my extension there is no service definition and I don't see it neither in vendors.

So the question is quite simple:

How to inject the securityContext in my extended SonataUser Admin's class ?

Comment: Another solution in http://stackoverflow.com/a/25258001/260389

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After weeks of search with no response at all on none of my questions,
I finally found a SonataAdmin service definition example.

Here is what looks like mine:

```
services:
    sonata.admin.user:
        class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Admin\Entity\UserAdmin
        tags:
            - {name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: user, label: users}
        arguments:
            - null
            - Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
            - 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD'
        calls:
            - [setTranslationDomain, [MyProjectBundle]]
            - [setUserManager, ['@fos_user.user_manager']]
            - [setSecurityContext, ['@security.context']]
```

Obviously `setSecurityContext()` have to be implemented into the admin class.

Comment: The [`security.context` service is deprecated](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements) since Symfony 2.6. For the record I personally don't use SonataAdmin anymore, hence getting rid of a big pain in my ass...